# Android Gradle Exception: Multiple dex files Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a multimodule project keeps getting this error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;\n","tool":"Dex"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

Here's all the module build.gradle:

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'mypackage'
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debugSigningConfig {
            storeFile file("debug-keystore.jks")
            storePassword "mypass"
            keyAlias "myalias"
            keyPassword "mypass"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugSigningConfig
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.2.0'
    compile project(':mod1')
    compile project(':mod2')
    compile project(':mod3')
}
```

**mod1 build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':mod4')
}
```

**mod2 build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':mod4')
}
```

**mod3 build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile project(':mod4')
    compile "com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0"
}
```

**mod4 build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile project(':mod5')
}
```

**mod5 build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion appCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion appBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion appMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion appTargetSdkVersion
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Variables:

```
supportLibraryVersion = "26.1.0"
playServicesVersion = "11.4.2"
appCompileSdkVersion = 26
appBuildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
appMinSdkVersion = 15
appTargetSdkVersion = 26
```

The result from `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath` is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

releaseCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: release
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7 -> 2.8.2
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.5
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.17
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13
|    |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13 (*)
+--- com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 -> 27.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1 -> 27.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1 -> 27.0.0
+--- project :mod1
|    \--- project :mod4
|         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:design:27.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
|         +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         +--- com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2
|         |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2
|         |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.0 (*)
|         |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.4.2
|         |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2
|         |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.4.2
|         |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl-license:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-license:11.4.2
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-license:11.4.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity-license:11.4.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-license:11.4.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.4.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.4.2
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.4.2
|         \--- project :mod5
|              \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- project :mod2
|    \--- project :mod4 (*)
\--- project :mod3
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0 (*)
     +--- project :mod4 (*)
     \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

All of my tries:

- `Clean` then `Rebuild Project`
- Deleted `.gradle` and `build` folders
- `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- Deleted user `.gradle` folder

Don't know what more can i do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Add output for `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`

Comment: What are your `appCompileSdkVersion `,  `appBuildToolsVersion `, `playServicesVersion ` and `supportLibraryVersion ` variables values?

Comment: I've edited the post with output and variable values.

Comment: @DeKaNszn i've edited the original post with the output and variable values.

Comment: @tomacco i've edited the original post with the output and variable values.

Comment: @MarceloBaccelli You wrote `supportLibraryVersion = "26.1.0"`, but in your log: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0`. May be you post incorrect values for variables?

Comment: @DeKaNszn sorry, i've tryied to change the value and copy the wrong number. But work neither 26.1.0 or 27.0.0.

Comment: @MarceloBaccelli `releaseCompileClasspath` doesn't contain problems. Is output for `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath` equal to posted?

Comment: @MarceloBaccelli Support library versions should match the `compileSdkVersion`. You declare them correctly but gradle is forcing version 27.0.0 instead of the one you declared. Try to set the `compileSdkVersion` to 27.

Comment: @DeKaNszn i've find the error. Two libs (different version) was inside libs folder of the mod4. Wasn't a module made by me, so it's was copied over the newer lib and the oldest still there. Thanks!

Comment: What Android plugin version do you use? (File > Project Structure > Project) I get the same issue after changing from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0. Migrating to the new version seems to require some changes on the gradle file (which I don't know yet): https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0